# Why is Intel MKL called a Math "Kernel" library?

Tags: kernel

I was always under the impression that the Intel MKL routines were written in C/Fortran and sometimes hand-optimized at the assembly level, but I don't see how these are associated with the kernel - is there a technical reason why it is called a "kernel library"? The only other usage of this term I've found is for the "Linux Kernel Library", whose name makes much more sense in its context.

Answer (score -1):

From [Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel):

> In numerical analysis, a subroutine that performs a common numerical operation
>   In particular, a routine that is executed in a vectorized loop

And from [Compute kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compute_kernel):

> In computing, a compute kernel is a routine compiled for high
>   throughput accelerators (such as GPUs), DSPs or FPGAs, separate from
>   (but used by) a main program. They are sometimes called compute
>   shaders, sharing execution units with vertex shaders and pixel shaders
>   on GPUs, but are not limited to execution on one class of device, or
>   graphics APIs.

Answer (score -2):

Kernel libraries directly hook into and are used by the kernel, hence 'kernel library'.

Comment: "Kernel" in mathematics, as in Intel's "math kernel libraries", has a very specific meaning which has very little to do with operating system kernels. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel#Mathematics for a bit of background. Intel's MKL is an ordinary userspace library; the "kernel" in the name comes from the mathematical background.